# Python Enum _value2member_map_ Accessor?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I created an enum base class to standardize reverse lookups on simple enums.

```
from enum import Enum

class ReversibleEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def fromName(cls, str):
        return getattr(cls, str.lower())

    @classmethod
    def fromValue(cls, value):
        return cls._value2member_map_[value]
```

Is there is an official way to get one's hands on the `_value2member_map_` dict? (or is there a standard way to do this that I missed?)

Thanks!

Comment: The loop is unnecessary. Just return `cls._value2member_map_[value]` (and catch the possible `KeyError` to raise your custom exception).

Comment: Lol, good point. I'll fix the example as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Getting members is supported both by name and by value:

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3
```

```
>>> Color['RED']    # note square brackets
<Color.RED: 1>

>>> Color(1)
<Color.RED: 1>      # note round parenthesis
```